# Apache Spark SQL results not spilling to disk, exhausting Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

According to the Spark FAQ:

> Does my data need to fit in memory to use Spark?
>
> No. Spark's operators spill data to disk if it does not fit in memory,
>   allowing it to run well on any sized data. Likewise, cached datasets
>   that do not fit in memory are either spilled to disk or recomputed on
>   the fly when needed, as determined by the RDD's storage level.

I'm querying a big table of 50 million entries. The initial data download won't fit in RAM, so Spark should spill to disk, right? And I filter out a small number of entries from those, which will fit in RAM.

`SPARK_CLASSPATH=postgresql-9.4.1208.jre6-2.jar ./bin/pyspark --num-executors 4`

```
url = \
  "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase?user=postgres"

df = sqlContext \
  .read \
  .format("jdbc") \
  .option("url", url) \
  .option("dbtable", "accounts") \
  .option("partitionColumn", "id") \
  .option("numPartitions", 10) \
  .option("lowerBound", 1) \
  .option("upperBound", 50000000) \
  .option("password", "password") \
  .load()

# get the small number of accounts whose names contain "taco"
results = df.map(lambda row: row["name"]).filter(lambda name: "taco" in name).collect()
```

I see some queries run on the  Postgres server, then they finish, and `pyspark` crashes due to the Java backend crashing. `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

Is there something else I need to do?